# Audio device is disapeared from my laptop from any OS

Tags: laptop, audio, hardware-failure

I have a Asus KSeries laptop and today I have faced this issue that audio device is disapeared from the list of pci devices and is not available any more, even it is not avaiable inside other operation systems. No audio device is avaialbe anymore.

[comparision of lspci output from my laptop and similar model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFgfo.png)

So is there any idea what actually has happened to my laptop?

Comment: Is it possible to disable the on-board audio in the BIOS/UEFI?

Comment: Nah, it doesn't provide any option for audio devices

Comment: If the BIOS is not up to date, now might be a good time to do that in case it prods it into working. Assuming you're using Ubuntu, [ASUS K501U Ubuntu Post Install Set Up](https://github.com/lshannon/ASUS-K501U-Ubuntu-Set-Up/blob/master/README.md) has a hint in the [Getting WiFi to work](https://github.com/lshannon/ASUS-K501U-Ubuntu-Set-Up/blob/master/README.md#getting-wifi-to-work) section that it might be possible to change BIOS settings from the command line, but you would have to investigate further and proceed cautiously.

Comment: Sounds like the audio chip failed. Have you been plugging different things in to the jacks? Maybe you fed some power back in to the chip or shorted something out. Either way it sounds like it might be toast.

Comment: Test it from installation media, e.g. a Live Ubuntu USB stick. If that works, you know it's OS, not hardware issue.

Comment: @Appleoddity, I'm afraid if it's a bug inside my laptop

Comment: @DrMoishePippik, already tried that

Comment: Then you've answered you're own question, if it does not work from external boot media.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by letting the laptop to drain the battery and leaving the laptop off for about one hour with empty battery and then turning on again!